# How to disable Firebase in Unity for iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase

I'm using an official firebase package for push notifications in android in unity, but I want to disable firebase for iOS build. Is it possible? I tried to disable iOS platform in Firebase settings, but it's still saying that I need to add `GooglePlayServices-info.plist` to iOS project and add some useless pods.

Comment: You should look into [Platform Dependent Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).